# LaTeX: Redefining starred command

Tags: latex, tex

I want to redefine the `\part*` command so that it automatically adds a contents line. This proves difficult since I want to reuse the original `\part*` command inside my starred version.

Normally (i.e. for unstarred commands) I would do it like this:

```
\let\old@part\part
\renewcommand\part[2][]{
  \old@part[#1]{#2}
  … rest of definition}
```

That is, I would save the original definition of `\part` in `\old@part` and use that.

However, this doesn’t work for starred commands since they don’t define a single lexeme (unlike the `\part` command in the example above). This boils down to the following question: **How can I save a starred command?**

Notice that I already know how to redefine a starred command itself, using the `\WithSuffix` command from the `suffix` package. This isn’t the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `\part*` command. What happens is the `\part` command takes a look at the next character after it (with `\@ifstar`) and dispatches to one of two other routines that does the actual work based on whether there's an asterisk there or not.

Reference: TeX FAQ entry [Commands defined with * options](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cmdstar)

Comment: “There is no `\part*` command.” – I know. :-( Otherwise I wouldn’t have this problem.

Comment: So then redefine `\part` like you have and handle both versions? Or dig into the LaTeX source and redefine the underlying starred-`\part` code?

Comment: … but this was the vital hint. I’ve got the it working now. Will post the solution shortly.

Comment: Could you say why you'd want to redefine `\part*` to add a TOC entry? Because not adding one is sort of the point of providing a starred version in the first place, and it sounds kind of silly.

Comment: @sgm: The starred version of `\part` is also *unnumbered*, which is what I want. The alternative would have been to redefine the unstarred version to be unnumbered but I felt that this would be even less consistent, since starring a command is pretty much the convention to make a command unnumbered, not only in section headings.

Comment: If that is the case, I'd suggest the use of the *titlesec* package to modify the styles of headings, which is going to end up being much easier, and unsurprising to other "LaTeXnicians", rather than messing with redefining commands.

Comment: Thanks for the package suggestion, this looks like it could save me some work. Up until now, I’ve always completely redefined header commands when I wanted to style them.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @smg’s answer, I’ve cobbled together a solution that works perfectly. Here’s the complete source, along with explanatory comments:

```
% If this is in *.tex file, uncomment the following line.
%\makeatletter

% Save the original \part declaration
\let\old@part\part

% To that definition, add a new special starred version.
\WithSuffix\def\part*{
  % Handle the optional parameter.
  \ifx\next[%
    \let\next\thesis@part@star%
  \else
    \def\next{\thesis@part@star[]}%
  \fi
  \next}

% The actual macro definition.
\def\thesis@part@star[#1]#2{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
   {% If the first argument isn’t given, default to the second one.
    \def\thesis@part@short{#2}
    % Insert the actual (unnumbered) \part header.
    \old@part*{#2}}
   {% Short name is given.
    \def\thesis@part@short{#1}
    % Insert the actual (unnumbered) \part header with short name.
    \old@part*[#1]{#2}}

  % Last, add the part to the table of contents. Use the short name, if provided.
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thesis@part@short}
}

% If this is in *.tex file, uncomment the following line.
%\makeatother
```

(This needs the packages `suffix` and `ifthen`.)

Now, we can use it:

```
\part*{Example 1}
This will be an unnumbered part that appears in the TOC.

\part{Example 2}
Yes, the unstarred version of \verb/\part/ still works, too.
```